# Plot 3D phase portrait

Tags: matlab, ode

Given the system of equations:

```
x' = 9x -21y - 10z
y' = 22x -35 - 22z
z'= -22x +34y +21z
```

I have to plot its phase portrait using this code:

```
function test
    A=[9   -21   -10;
       22   -35   -22;
      -22    34    21]; 

    [vals,vector]=eig(A);

    x0=[-0.8,0.8]; %[1,-1, 0.2];%
    y0=[   0,  0]; %[0, 0, 0.4];%
    z0=[-0.9,0.9]; %[1,-1,-0.4];%
    Tmax=2;

    plot3([-10 10],[0 0],[0 0],'k')
    hold on
    grid on
    plot3([0 0],[-10 10],[0 0],'k')
    plot3([0 0],[0 0],[-10 10],'k')

    axis([-10,10,-10,10,-10,10])

    for k=1:length(x0)
        [t,y]=ode45(@sys3d,[0,Tmax],[x0(k),y0(k),z0(k)]);
        plot3(y(:,1),y(:,2),y(:,3))
        [t,y]=ode45(@sys3d,[0,-Tmax],[x0(k),y0(k),z0(k)]);
        plot3(y(:,1),y(:,2),y(:,3))
    end
end

function res=sys3d(t,y)
    A=[-2  1  0;
       -1 -2 -1;
        0  3 -2]; 
    res=A*y;
end
```

My questions are :

> Where do `x0`,`y0`, `z0` and `Tmax` come from? And if first line was
>   `9x - 21y - 10z + 5` where would `5` goes in the matrix?

Comment: Can't you ask the person who wrote the code? And minor note: it's MATLAB without an H: it comes from MATrix LABoratory:)

Comment: The code is from a textbook and I don't really understand it.

Comment: I find that highly surprising. In the code `x0`,`y0`,... are arbitrary initial values. The author probably pulled them out of thin air. If the differential equation had a 5 on the right hand side, it would no longer be homogeneous, so the exact same solution would probably not be applicable. Does the textbook not *teach* anything along these lines?

Comment: Can you give me directions how to make the phase portrait?

Comment: How is that question related to your question and code above?